# How to Know if an specific windows service is installed with Node js?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm new in Node JS.

I'm building an new desktop app with web-kit.

One of my requirements is verify if an determinate service is installed on Windows. How can I do that on Node js?

I know how to find the application at the process list with Node Js. But what I really need is whether it is installed, because it can be stopped, but installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you an array of all installed services:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
exec("sc query state= all", function(err, stdout) {
    var lines = stdout.toString().split("\r\n").filter(function (line) {
        return line.indexOf("SERVICE_NAME") !== -1;
    }).map(function (line) {
        return line.replace("SERVICE_NAME: ", "");
    });
    console.log(lines);
});
```